# Arboles Binarios C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Tengo que construir una función que reciba el árbol y la clave, buscar la clave y a partir de ahí indicar cuantos nodos descendientes hay.

Entonces tengo esta función únicamente para buscar la clave:

```
int NodosDescendientes(ArbolABB *ABB, int clave)
{
    if(!arbolABBVacio(ABB))
    {
        if(*(ABB->clave) == clave)
        {
            return CNodosDescendientes(ABB);
        }
        else if (*(ABB->clave) < clave)
        {
            NodosDescendientes(ABB->der,clave);
        }
        else NodosDescendientes(ABB->izq,clave);              
    }
}
```

Hasta ahí todo está perfecto, encuentra la clave y ejecuta la función CNodosDescendientes que es donde está el error, debería contarme los nodos descendientes pero no los cuenta, no sé si puede estar mal el recorrido o el como abordo el problema, esta es la función:

```
int CNodosDescendientes(ArbolABB *ABB)
{
    int contador = 0;

    if(!arbolABBVacio(ABB))
    {
        if(ABB->izq != NULL && ABB->der != NULL) 
        {
            contador++;
            CNodosDescendientes(ABB->izq);
            CNodosDescendientes(ABB->der);
        }

    }

    return contador;
}
```

Comment: Veo que solo haces la invocacion recursiva si ambas ramas (izquierda y drecha) existen. A mi parecer deberias aumentar el contador luego del primer if y luego pregunar si hay izquierda. Si hay le sumas al contador lo que te diga la invocación recursiva de la izquierda. Luego preguntas por la derecha, si hay entonces sumas al contador lo que te de la llamada recursiva de la derecha.

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando en [tag:c] o en [tag:c++]? Cada lenguaje tendrá una respuesta completamente distinta.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en C

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con( cuando lo utilizes restale 1 ya que se cuenta a si mismo):

```
int CNodosDescendientes(ArbolABB *ABB)
{
int contador = 0;

if(!arbolABBVacio(ABB))
{
    contador++;

    if(ABB->izq != NULL && ABB->der != NULL) 
    {


        contador+=CNodosDescendientes(ABB->izq);
        contador+=CNodosDescendientes(ABB->der);

    }

}

return contador;
}
```

Comment: Por alguna razón me sigue contando mal, ahora estoy dudando de que tan buena esté la otra función será mejor volver a replantear el problema